# Manage user restrictions to different apps within a single B2C Tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Within a single Azure AD B2C Tenant I have a directory of Users. Also, I have 2 Applications registered. Call them *App1* and *App2*.

Assume that a User has registered his/her Account coming from (and being redirected back to) *App1*, now that the user is in the common User directory, he/she could also sign in to *App2* and I can't do anything about it.

It doesn't make much sense to me, and I need to restrict it. How can I control which Apps the Users can access? A User could have access to any amount of registered Applications. I can't seem to find that in the Azure Portal...

Of course I can apply any solution also on App side, e.g. by checking some claim or something, but still, I need to know how to manage such restrictions. (this could be a fully custom way)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement in B2C exactly what you said you'd implement in the app

> by checking some claim or something

Apart of your B2C user journey you would introduce a precondition to check whether a claim exists or equals a certain value. This would require custom policies. There isn't an easy way to "error" out, but you could create a self asserted page that just shows an error message with a dummy input claim.

You're much better off building this logic in your application.

```
 <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>app_permission</Value>
          <Value>portalapp</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AppRestrictionExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="TechnicalProfileHere" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: But how do I persist whether a User in the directory has the claim or not? (e.g. as you described "app_permission" = "portalapp"). It must be attached to the User. We don't have a User Repository within the App, I'd rather store it on Azure side.

Comment: @thmshd my reference to 'app_permission' would be an extended schema attribute you would set on the user in the B2C tenant. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr